# Looking for a more efficient way to restructure data based on date and a grouping variable in SAS

Tags: date, sas, retain

Original data:

```
subject medgrp  stdt        endt
1       A       7/1/2014    7/31/2014
1       A       7/29/2014   8/30/2014
1       B       7/1/2014    8/15/2014
1       C       8/1/2014    9/1/2014
2       A       4/15/2014   5/15/2014
2       A       5/10/2014   6/10/2014
2       A       6/5/2014    6/15/2014
2       A       7/1/2014    8/1/2014
3       A       6/5/2014    6/15/2014
3       A       6/16/2014   8/1/2014
```

Re-structured data:

```
subject med_pattern stdt_new    endt_new
1       A*B         7/1/2014    7/31/2014
1       A*B*C       8/1/2014    8/15/2014
1       A*C         8/16/2014   8/30/2014
1       C           8/31/2014   9/1/2014
2       A           4/15/2014   6/15/2014
2       A           7/1/2014    8/1/2014
3       A           6/5/2014    8/1/2014
```

I was able to transform original data to re-structured data by outputting `stdt` to `endt` for all records, then keep one date for each `subject/medgrp`, reform date periods and create the variable `med_pattern`.

However, this method takes a long time to run, especially for big data (>3m records).

Any suggestions to make this more efficient would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code you used to transform the original data

Comment: Please update your question with your sample data as text, not as an image.

Comment: Do you have SAS/CONNECT? You already have some logic that produces the correct output, so you can make it up to n times faster without too much extra work if you split up your data into n pieces and process them in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

By `subject` you can use a date keyed multi-data hash to track the `medgrp` activity for each date in the date range defined by `stdt` and `endt`.  A iteration of the hash will let you compute your medgrps *crossings* value.

```
data have; input 
subject medgrp $ stdt: mmddyy8. endt: mmddyy8.; format stdt endt mmddyy10.;
datalines;
1       A       7/1/2014    7/31/2014
1       A       7/29/2014   8/30/2014
1       B       7/1/2014    8/15/2014
1       A       7/15/2014   7/15/2014
1       C       8/1/2014    9/1/2014
2       A       4/15/2014   5/15/2014
2       A       5/10/2014   6/10/2014
2       A       6/5/2014    6/15/2014
2       A       7/1/2014    8/1/2014
3       A       6/5/2014    6/15/2014
3       A       6/16/2014   8/1/2014
;

data crossings_by_date / view=crossings_by_date;
  if 0 then set have; * prep PDV;

  if _n_ then do;    
    declare hash dg(multidata:'yes', ordered:'a');         %* 1st hash for subject dates;
    dg.defineKey('date');
    dg.defineData('date', 'medgrp');
    dg.defineDone();
    call missing (date); format date adate cdate mmddyy10.;

    declare hash crossing(ordered:'a');                    %* 2nd hash for deduping a list of medgrps ;
    crossing.defineKey('medgrp');
    crossing.defineData('medgrp');
    crossing.defineDone();

    declare hiter dgi('dg');
    declare hiter xi('crossing');
  end;

  dg.clear();

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.subject);  * process subjects one by one;
    set have;
    by subject;
    do date = stdt to endt; * load multidata hash with medgrp over date range;
      dg.add();
    end;
  end;

  * examine each date in which subject had activity; 
  adate = .;
  cdate = -1e9;
  do _i_ = 1 by 1 while (dgi.next() = 0);
    if date eq adate 
      then continue;          * hiter over multi-data will return each node;
      else adate = date;      * track activity date;

    * load hash to dedupe tracking of medgrp on date;
    crossing.clear();
    do _i_ = 1 by 1 while (dg.do_over() = 0);
      crossing.replace();
    end;

    * compute crossing representation on date, A*B*... by traversing 2nd hash;
    xi.first();      length cross $20;
    cross = medgrp;
    do while(0 = xi.next());
      cross = catx('*',cross,medgrp);
    end;

    if date - cdate > 1 then cluster + 1;    %* track cluster based on date continuities;
    cdate = date;

    output;  * <------------ view OUTPUT;
  end;

  keep subject date cross cluster;
run;

* 2nd data step processes view (1st data step);
* determine when date continuity ends or medgrp changes;

data want;
  length subject 8 medgrps $20;
  format stdt endt mmddyy10.;

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.medgrps);
    set crossings_by_date (rename=cross=medgrps);
    by cluster medgrps notsorted;

    if stdt = . then 
      stdt = date;
  end;

  endt = date;

  keep subject medgrps stdt endt; 
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this approach. I've never come across multi-data hash. It sure works, but my only concern is that it's taking even more time to run than my original approach. I tested it using a 10k dataset. My approach took 6.61s and this one took 21s to run.

Comment: I am surprised it takes that long, but don't have any data to troubleshoot.  Perhaps some of the date ranges are very big ?   How many subjects in the 10K data set ?  What are some of the date ranges that a subject will exhibit ? Can you show the log from your 10K run -- it will tell how many rows the view sent out ?  One possible suspect is the hash resets `dg.CLEAR()` and `crossing.CLEAR()` being time consuming.  There are direct-index array based versions that could be much faster if you allow preconditions on max overall date ranges and number of groups  and crossings a subject experiences

Comment: If you want to supply 10K sample data you can link to something like google doc or pastebin.com entry